# PHP - Store & Calculate the total mark from radio input

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I have designed a small web-based system that have a school evaluation form to ask specific users who can access the system" some questions and the input will be a radio type ( 1 or 2 or 3 or 4)! 
the code is working and can inserts the input into the database but i don't know the correct query to calculate the total mark and store it in the database, this is currently working code below:

```
    <?php

   session_start();
   $Load=$_SESSION['login_user'];
   include('../connect.php');
   $sql= "Select name from student where ID='$Load'";
   $username = mysql_query($sql);
    $id=$_SESSION['login_user'];

                if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{  

   $v1 = $_POST['v1'];
   $v2 = $_POST['v2'];
   $v3 = $_POST['v3'];
   $total = $_POST['total'];

 mysql_query("INSERT into Form1 (P1,P2,P3,TOTAL)
 values('$v1','$v2','$v3','$total')") or die(mysql_error());
 header("Location: mark.php");
 }


?>


<html>

<head>

<?php


if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))

header("Location:index.html");



?>
  <title>Q&A Form</title>

</head>

<body>


    <center><form method="post" action=""  >

    <table style="width: 20%" >
        <tr>
    <th> Criteria </th>
    <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th> Excellent </th>
    <td >  4 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th > Good <font size="3" > </font></th>
    <td>  3 <font size="4" > </font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th > Average <font size="3" > </font></th>
    <td >  2 <font size="4" > </font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th > Poor <font size="3" > </font></th>
    <td >  1 <font size="4" > </td>
    </tr>




<font size='4'>
    <table style="width: 70%">
        <tr>
<th > School Evaluation <font size="4" > </font></th>

<tr>
<th > Criteria <font size="4" > </font></th>
            <th> 4<font size="4" > </font></th>
            <th> 3<font size="4" > </font></th>
            <th> 2<font size="4" > </font></th>
            <th> 1<font size="4" > </font></th>

        </tr>
<tr>
<th> Your attendance<font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "4"    checked = "checked" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "3"     /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "2"     /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "1"     /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th > Your grades  <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "4"    checked = "checked" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "3"     /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "2"     /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "1"     /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th >Your self-control <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "4"    checked = "checked" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "3"     /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "2"     /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "1"     /></td>    
</tr>       


        </tr>
    </table>


    <br>
    <a href="evaE.php">  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="clear" style="width: 70px"></td>
<?php
$total = $v1+ $v2 + $v3;

?>  


 </form> 
</center>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

i used this query but it doesn't work out .. any help please?

```
 <?php
    $total = $v1+ $v2 + $v3;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You want to store both the separate values and the sum, but you don't want to do the sum on your PHP?

If so, you could make a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), something like that:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `sum_values` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `Form1`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.TOTAL = NEW.P1 + NEW.P2 + NEW.P3;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This way, you'd only have to run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO 
    Form1 
        (P1,P2,P3)
    VALUES
        ('$v1','$v2','$v3')
```

... and the trigger should fill the 'total' column with the sum P1 + P2 + P3.

This trigger I created will basically says: "everytime someone inserts something into 'Form1', fill the 'TOTAL' column with the sum P1 + P2 + P3".

Also, you should NOT be using mysql_query. Check out mysqli or PDO_MySQL. mysql_query is outdated, was discontinued and is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side technology, it cannot respond to changes in a page without submitting to the server, maybe with an AJAX call or something. However what it appears you need to do is set up some onclick events and use javascript to add your total up into a hidden element in your form and submit that along with the rest.

```
...
<tr>
<th> Your attendance<font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "4"    checked = "checked" onclick="updateTotal();"/></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "3"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "2"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "1"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th > Your grades  <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "4"  onclick="updateTotal();"  checked = "checked" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "3"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "2"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "1"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th >Your self-control <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "4"  onclick="updateTotal();"  checked = "checked" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "3"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "2"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "1"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>    
</tr>       


        </tr>
    </table>


    <br>
    <a href="evaE.php">  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="clear" style="width: 70px"></td>

    <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" />


<script>
  function updateTotal(){

    var sumRad = 0;

    var arrV1 = document.getElementsByName("v1");
    var arrV2 = document.getElementsByName("v2");
    var arrV3 = document.getElementsByName("v3");

    for(var i=0; i<arrV1.length ; i++){
      if(arrV1[i].checked == true){
        sumRad += parseInt(arrV1[i].value);
      }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<arrV2.length ; i++){
      if(arrV2[i].checked == true){
        sumRad += parseInt(arrV2[i].value);
      }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<arrV3.length ; i++){
      if(arrV3[i].checked == true){
        sumRad += parseInt(arrV3[i].value);
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('total').value = sumRad ;
  }
</script>


 </form> 
</center>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Corrected to account for JS treating values as strings by default.

Comment: i've used ur code , it stored the total in the database like 1232444444 .. not doing the sum!

Comment: @user1806136 -  JS parsed the value as string by default, silly of me to forget, change `sumRad += arrV1[i].value;` to `sumRad += parseInt(arrV1[i].value);` for each set of radios and you should be good to go.