# php - how to store the sum operation in database

Tags: php, sum

i've used this code to calcuate the sum (total) of v1,v2,v3 wihch is a radio input type , everything stored ok in the database expect of TOTAL .. it stores like 144 or 444! not the sum of all 3 inputs.. please help i want to store it as sum of the 3 inputs

```
...
<tr>
<th> Your attendance<font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "4"    checked = "checked" onclick="updateTotal();"/></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "3"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "2"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "1"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th > Your grades  <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "4"  onclick="updateTotal();"  checked = "checked" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "3"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "2"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "1"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th >Your self-control <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "4"  onclick="updateTotal();"  checked = "checked" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "3"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "2"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "1"  onclick="updateTotal();"   /></td>    
</tr>       


        </tr>
    </table>


    <br>
    <a href="evaE.php">  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="clear" style="width: 70px"></td>

    <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" />


<script>
  function updateTotal(){

    var sumRad = 0;

    var arrV1 = document.getElementsByName("v1");
    var arrV2 = document.getElementsByName("v2");
    var arrV3 = document.getElementsByName("v3");

    for(var i=0; i<arrV1.length ; i++){
      if(arrV1[i].checked == true){
        sumRad += arrV1[i].value;
      }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<arrV2.length ; i++){
      if(arrV2[i].checked == true){
        sumRad += arrV2[i].value;
      }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<arrV3.length ; i++){
      if(arrV3[i].checked == true){
        sumRad += arrV3[i].value;
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('total').value = sumRad ;
  }
</script>


 </form> 
</center>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

the rest of the code is

```
       <?php

   session_start();
   $Load=$_SESSION['login_user'];
   include('../connect.php');
   $sql= "Select name from student where ID='$Load'";
   $username = mysql_query($sql);
    $id=$_SESSION['login_user'];

                if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{  

   $v1 = $_POST['v1'];
   $v2 = $_POST['v2'];
   $v3 = $_POST['v3'];
   $total = $_POST['total'];

 mysql_query("INSERT into Form1 (P1,P2,P3,TOTAL)
 values('$v1','$v2','$v3','$total')") or die(mysql_error());
 header("Location: mark.php");
 }


?>
```

Comment: What's with the answers from your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312033/php-store-calculate-the-total-mark-from-radio-input)? And why don't you just add them in PHP  right when you receive them?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to `parseInt()` on the `sumRad += arrV1[i].value;`

eg `sumRad += parseInt(arrv1[i].value,10)`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you are actually doing a string concatentation since values for each of these fields is not an integer representation but s string representation. To get your sum you should do something like:

```
sumRad += parseInt(arrV1[i].value);
```

I would also agree with the comment questioning why you are even doing the summation in javascript.  You are just updating a hidden field, so you could just as easily remove the hidden filed and all associated javascript and simply do the summation in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you make a sum:

```
$v1 = intval($_POST['v1']);
$v2 = intval($_POST['v2']);
$v3 = intval($_POST['v3']);
$total = $v1 + $v2 + $v3;
```

Doing it in Javascript is nice for display, but not overly reliable (could be disabled, even if rarely).

Here [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) makes an acceptable substitute for [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) that you *ought to use* when you use the dated database interface, instead of the simpler [`PDO`](http://php.net/PDO) with prepared statemens.